# How to fix Port Forwarding not working on TP LInk Router?

Tags: networking, dns, port-forwarding, wan, web-hosting

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFmwq.png)

[Screen Shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4SGM.png)

When i port forwarded from TL-WR840N i can access my site from local network by using wan IP Address which starts with 10 Private IP

but when i try to access it from another network i can't access it

even when i try to access with my public IP Address which i got from google by typing my IP Address starts from 45 still can't access even from local network

**How to do I solve this problem?**

Edit:

I Fixed This Problem By Simply Changing The Package My Isp Was Providing There are two kinds of package

1. Shared Ip
2. Real Ip

So My Current Ip is on Real Ip Package and yeah everything works fine now. Hopefully You'll figure out if you have same problem.

Comment: The 10. Address should not be a WAN address as its not globally routable. Are you sure that's your WAN address? If so, your provider is doing NAT (badly) and you won't be able to achieve this without getting a VPN or similar or changing your connectivity.

Comment: I will change isp to another
a screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFmwq.png

Comment: That screenshot implies you may be using PPPoE and I'm unsure if the WAN interface is showing your actual address( I suspect its not and the 10.x.x.x IP only connects to your ISP, with your actual connection being "dialed up" on top of it ) Can you log into the router, go to Advanced routing->System routing table and show what that says. This likely won't tell us the IP, but could provide clues we need .

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4SGM.png This Comes up

Comment: Images are all dead.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to access your local network from the wider Internet unless you either change ISP or ISP plan or work with your ISP or add a VPN which gives you a world-routable address.

Looking at the last line of the routing table (ID 4) it shows a Destination network of 0.0.0.0, with a subnet mask of 0.0.0.0 and gateway of 10.31.0.1.  This means that your gateway is on the 10.x.x.x range, which is problematic.   Somewhere down the line, they are converting your 10.x.x.x IP address, along with a whole lot of other people, to an address starting 45... but this means you can make outbound connections, but an inbound connection will not work, as it can't uniquely identify your network.

The core of the issue is your ISP is providing you with an IP address out of what is called [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) space - which are set aside as "Address Allocation for Private Internets" **and are not visible from the Internet**.  *The simple take-away* is your ISP is (a) not providing you a proper Internet service and (b) is cheap and incompetent.   [ I say this because there are solutions to this problem.   The cheap one is to use CGN, which requires a different IP range but does not help you here - you need a real address, and incompetent because [they should be using the range 100.64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

The solution requires you to get an address which is actually world routable (ie you need tot make sure the provider is not using NAT)  You can either get a valid - ideally static - IP address from a provider, or you can set up a VPN on top of your existing connection to deliver a real IP address from the Internet to your computer and use that.   If you are going the VPN route, make sure you specifically find a provider that will allocate you a unique, static IP address.  They do exist, but its different to using an VPN provider for anonymity.  (Google "VPN Static IP" for a list of providers).